# How to do (or code) so that an array of Bullet objects can meet with an array of Zombie objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I just started learning game development using **Java**.

I have created

1. ArrayList of class Zombie
2. ArrayList of class Bullet

Each of the object in the two ArrayList has a variable called *rect* of type Rectangle which surrounds their own graphics on screen.

**My aim is** to make an effect when any bullet meets any zombie.

**My problem is** I don't know how to do "any bullet meets any zombie."

**My method:** I used the *rect* variable to test whether both of the object have collided with each other by using the method *rect.intersect(r)*. I'm testing every single bullet in the Bullet ArrayList to see if it has collided with any zombie in the Zombie ArrayList, which means I run through the two ArrayList completely per frame just to carry this feature out. There must be better ways..??

Comment: show some code you have done

Comment: *...which means I run through the two Lists completely per frame just to carry this feature out.*  There is no better way.

Comment: Maybe you can optimize... depends on your game. For example, sort both lists by x position, then you can ignore any bullets that are further to the right than the right most zombie. Same for y. Not sure how much you'd gain though. Like with all optimizations, get a profiler first and see where your code spends its time.

Answer (score 1):

The only "better way" would be to run your collision detection on a separate thread so you can be detecting collisions while doing other logic.
This would not be the easiest thing to implement so unless you are experience massive slowdowns from collision detection I would recommend you continue as you are.

You could also try to narrow down the candidates for collision detection...

For example if some of the zombies/bullets are off screen you probably don't care if collision happens so you could completely skip said entity.

Yes you would have to first check if the entities are in the screen rect but that's only running through each list once and could potentially save you from running through a bunch of collision detection that you don't care about anyway.

TL;DR: If you aren't experience any massive performance drops I would try to just keep playing around with it and build your understanding of collision detection first, then worry about optimizations.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: You're going to have to check each bullet to see whether or not they're off the screen each frame if you're trying to "narrow" collision detection so there's not much gained there. The current approach is the most efficient & easiest to implement